# How does a typical Rcpp edit-compile-test cycle look like?

Tags: r, rcpp

I can only find information on how to install a ready-made R extension package, but it is nowhere mentioned which commands a developer of an extension package has to use during daily development. I am using Rcpp and I am on Windows.

If this were a typical C++ project, it would go like this:

```
edit
make  # oops, typo
edit  # fix typo
make  # oops, forgot an #include
edit
make  # good; updates header dependencies for subsequent 'make' automatically
./fooreader  # test it
make install # only now I'm ready
```

Which commands do I need for daily development of an Rcpp package project?

I've allocated a skeleton project using these commands from the R command line:

```
library(Rcpp)
Rcpp.package.skeleton("FooReader", example_code=FALSE,
         author="My Name", email="my.email@example.com")
```

This allocated 3 files:

```
DESCRIPTION
NAMESPACE
man/FooReader-package.Rd
```

Now I dropped source code into

```
src/readfoo.cpp
```

with these contents:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

#error here
```

I know I can run this from the R command line:

```
Rcpp::sourceCpp("D:/Projects/FooReader/src/readfoo.cpp")
```

(this does run the compiler and indicates the #error).
But I want to develop a package ultimately.

Answer (score 2):

There is no universal answer for everybody, I guess.

For some people, RStudio is everything, and with some reason. One can use the package creation facility to create an Rcpp package, then edit and just hit the buttons (or keyboard shortcuts) to compile and re-load and test.

I also work a lot on a shell, so I do a fair amount of editing in Emacs/ESS along with `R CMD INSTALL` (where thanks to `ccache` recompilation of unchanged code is immediate) with command-line use via `r` of the littler package -- this allows me to write compact expressions loading the new package and evaluating: `r -lnewpackage -esomeFunc(somearg)` to test `newpackage::someFunc()` with `somearg`.
You can also launch the build and test from Emacs.  As I said, it all depends.

Both those answers are for package, where I do real work. When I just test something in a single file, I do that in one Emacs buffer and `sourceCpp()` in an R session in another buffer of the same Emacs.  Or sometimes I edit in Emacs and run `sourceCpp()` in RStudio.

There is no one answer. Find what works for you.

Also, the first part of your question describes the *initial setup* of a package. That is not part of the edit/compile/link/test cycle as it is a one off.  And for that too do we have *different* approaches many of which have been discussed here.

*Edit:* The other **main** misunderstanding of your question is that *once you have package* you generally *do not use `sourceCpp()`* anymore.

Comment: Thanks. You say there is no universal answer. My problem is that there is not even a single answer. Can you expand on one workflow that uses the shell (similar to edit-make-test-repeat) and does not involve RStudio (I want to avoid it unless everybody agrees that other workflows are drainbamaged).

Comment: Do exactly what the R manuals describe: `R CMD build mypkg` followed by `R CMD check mypkg*tar.gz` followed by `R CMD INSTALL mypkg*tar.gz` followed by running _your_ test code.  I have helper scripts `build.r` and `check.r` (or `rcc.r`) and `install.r` in littler.  None of this is new, all of this is the same as for _every_ other R package.  No free lunch, no short cuts.

Comment: Other people use `devtools` too; I had my workflows I still like before it was written so I don't use it.  Your mileage may vary, _you_ need to experiment and find your way.

Comment: Sounds like the pendant to an `edit`-`make`-test cycle boils down to `edit`-`R CMD build`-`R CMD check`-`R CMD INSTALL`-test cycle. Would edit your answer accordingly?

Comment: No I would not as I meant want I wrote, and I don;t want you to edit my answer either.

Answer (score 1):

In order to test an R package, it has to be installed into a (temporary) library such that it can be attached to a running R process. So you will typically need:

- `R CMD build .` to build `package_version.tar.gz`
- `R CMD check <package_version.tar.gz>` to test your package, including tests placed into the `tests`folder
- `R CMD INSTALL <package_version.tar.gz>` to install it into a library

After that you can attach the package and test it. Quite often I try to use a more TTD approach, which means I do not have to `INSTALL` the package. Running the unit tests (e.g. via `R CMD check`) is enough.

All that is independent of Rcpp. For a package using Rcpp you need to call `Rcpp::compileAttributes()` before these steps, e.g. with `Rscript -e 'Rcpp::compileAttributes()'`.

If you use RStudio for package development, it offers a lot of automation via the `devtools` package. I still find it useful to know what has to go on under the hood and it is by no means required.

Comment: A lot of 'yes but' here.  RStudio does not require `devtools`; I use the former not the latter. `Rscript` can be used, as can `r`. Overall as you wrote -- and *exactly* as the [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html) manual has been saying for 20+ years.

Comment: Looks like I was looking for `R CMD SHLIB *.cpp`. But the sequence you suggest is useful after `SHLIB` produces a successful build.

Comment: @j6t This only tests compilation. If you want to make a short cut, you can call `R CMD INSTALL .` in the package directory.

Comment: @RalfStubner Sure, but `R CMD INSTALL` always rebuilds everything from scratch and takes an awful lot of time on Windows; that's unaffordable while I'm editing code in several `.cpp` files. It's the long way, not a shortcut.

Comment: @j6t When called on a package file `ccache` as mentioned by Dirk helps a lot. However, the trailing dot in my command is relevant. If you call `R CMD INSTALL <pkgDir>`, the compilation happens in that directory and the object files remain there. During the next call, only the changed files are recompiled. This works well if the automatic `make` rules get the dependencies right.

Comment: @RalfStubner If I call `R CMD INSTALL .` twice in a row and the first one completes successfully, I expect that the second call at least does not compile anything. That does not happen here: it still recompiles everything. (There was *no* change in the source code, of course.)

Comment: @j6t Strange, That is not the behavior I am seeing here.